# Testing Multiple Custom Validators with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

I am trying to run specs for two custom validators:

```
spec/validators/email_validator_spec.rb
spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb
```

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec/validators/` the `phone_validator_spec.rb` spec fails:

```
1) PhoneValidator with a valid phone number should be valid
     Failure/Error: subject.should be_valid
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb:18:in `each'
     # ./spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

However, when I run that spec individually using the command `bundle exec rspec spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb`, it passes.

When I remove the `email_validator_spec.rb` then `phone_validator_spec.rb` passes using the command `bundle exec rspec spec/validators/`.

I expect both specs to pass when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/validators/`. Can anyone explain to me what is happening?

**Update:**
Used zetetic's tip to print out the error hash:

```
1) PhoneValidator with a valid phone number should be valid
     Failure/Error: subject.errors.should == {}
       expected: {}
            got: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x37b2460 @base=#<Validatable:0x37b2700 @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x37b2460 ...>, @phone_number="1112223333">, @messages={:email=>["is invalid"]}> (using ==)
       Diff:
       @@ -1 +1,8 @@
       +#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x37b2460
       + @base=
       +  #<Validatable:0x37b2700
       +   @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x37b2460 ...>,
       +   @phone_number="1112223333",
       +   @validation_context=nil>,
       + @messages={:email=>["is invalid"]}>
     # ./spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb:18:in `each'
     # ./spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It appears the `Validatable` class definitions are combined when both specs are run. Is this behavior expected? If I use distinct class names, both specs pass.

**spec/validators/phone_validator_spec.rb**

```
require 'active_model'
require 'rspec/rails/extensions'
require File.expand_path('app/validators/phone_validator')

class Validatable
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :phone_number
  validates :phone_number, phone: true
end

describe PhoneValidator do

  subject { Validatable.new }

  describe "with a valid phone number" do
    it "should be valid" do
      phone_numbers = ["1112223333", "123222ABCD"]
      phone_numbers.each do |phone_number|
        subject.phone_number = phone_number
        subject.should be_valid
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

**app/validators/phone_validator.rb**

```
class PhoneValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    return if value.blank?
    unless value =~ /^[A-Za-z0-9]{10}$/
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/validators/email_validator_spec.rb**

```
require 'active_model'
require 'rspec/rails/extensions'
require File.expand_path('app/validators/email_validator')

class Validatable
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :email
  validates :email, email: true
end

describe EmailValidator do

  subject { Validatable.new }

  describe "with a valid email address" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        subject.email = valid_address
        subject.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "with an invalid phone number" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        subject.email = invalid_address
        subject.should be_invalid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/validators/email_validator.rb**

```
require 'mail'

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    begin
      m = Mail::Address.new(value)
      # We must check that value contains a domain and that value is an email address
      r = m.domain && m.address == value
      t = m.__send__(:tree)
      # We need to dig into treetop
      # A valid domain must have dot_atom_text elements size > 1
      # user@localhost is excluded
      # treetop must respond to domain
      # We exclude valid email values like <user@localhost.com>
      # Hence we use m.__send__(tree).domain
      r &&= (t.domain.dot_atom_text.elements.size > 1)
    rescue => e   
      r = false
    end
    object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid") unless r
  end
end
```

Using rails 3.2.11, rspec-rails 2.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model instance is invalid but you don't know why. Try changing

```
subject.should be_valid
```

to

```
subject.valid?
subject.errors.should == {}
```

Now the failure message will print out the error hash.

Another tip: [Don't rescue Exception](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/03/the-perils-of-rescue-exception/).

EDIT

*It appears the Validatable class definitions are combined when both specs are run. Is this behavior expected?*

Yes, that is normal for Ruby classes. When both spec files are required, each `Validatable` class body is executed, so you end up with a class that contains both validations.

You need to isolate the validations either by making the subjects pass the validation that is not under test, eg:

```
subject { Validatable.new(:email => "some value") }
```

or testing for the specific error message from the validation under test:

```
subject.valid?
subject.errors(:email).should include("is invalid")
```

PS. Seriously -- don't rescue Exception. Nothing good will come of that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It appears the two `Validatable` class definitions are causing the problem. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't want the specs to be dependent on each other, so I'm just going to give each Validatable class a unique name. I took your advice and removed the rescue Exception, too.

Answer (score 0):

I run in to this problem myself, and yes you could rename the class but the solution I used is to create and teardown the Validatable class inside your spec.

Here's a code snippet:

```
describe "HttpUriValidator",
  "Custom validator to ensure URL is a valid URI." do

  # Create the dummy class once when the test is run.
  before(:all) do
    class Validatable
      include ActiveModel::Validations
      attr_accessor  :url
      validates :url, http_uri: true
    end
  end
  # Must tearing down the class or it will taint other tests using its
  # name.
  after(:all) { Object.send(:remove_const, :Validatable) }

  subject { Validatable.new }
```

EDIT::

Just a heads up when you are declaring a Module wrapping your tested class (to avoid namespacing other classes in the test) ie.

```
module Foo::Bar
  describe Something do
    after(:all) { Foo::Bar.send(:remove_const, :Testable) }
  end
end
```

you will have to remove the constant from that namespace rather then Object.